# C# access class library from windows form application Two projects within one solution

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way for me to reference to a class library project, which is in the same solution as my windows form application ?

There are 5 windows form applications in my solution with one class library. Is it possible for me to reference to the class library without building it separately and copying the DLL each time.

Comment: Add Reference -> Project Reference tab -> Select other project

Comment: Can you tag your question with the version of Visual Studio you're using?

Comment: No research effort. Also @Tobsey answered it before you write your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Screen shots are for VS 2013*
**The steps to follow work for pretty much all versions**

Right click the `References` section in the solution explorer of the project you want to add the dll to
[image]

Select Add references, select "Solution" on the left hand side
[image]

You should see your project, check it to add a reference that will always be the latest compiled version of that project.

See MSDN for more on the [Add References dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)